# SAML consumer library for client side only

Tags: javascript, node.js, saml-2.0

Is there any SAML consumer library for javascript which works in browser only?

Most libraries i found need to be backed up by a node server (express).

But the onlly thing i need to do is sending a saml request to my IDPs saml endpoint and fetching (opt. validating) the SAML response.